# Encapsulating long-running functions in a "Please Wait" dialog

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a `PleaseWaitDialog` that functions as follows

```
Public Class PleaseWaitDialog

    Private RunFunction As Action(Of PleaseWaitDialog, List(Of Object))
    Private Args As List(Of Object)
    Friend WithEvents BackgroundWorker1 As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub New(RunFunction As Action(Of PleaseWaitDialog, List(Of Object)), Args As List(Of Object))
        Me.RunFunction = RunFunction
        Me.Args = Args
    End Sub

    Private Sub PleaseWaitDialog_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Me.RunFunction.Invoke(Me, Me.Args)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `PleaseWaitDialog` takes a delegate for a long-running method in its constructor, runs that method when the dialog is shown, then closes when the method completes.

In order to get this working for any existing long-running method, I have to take the existing function and alter its signature to take a `PleaseWaitDialog` and a list of argument objects, rather than having any type safety on the method. e.g.

```
Public Sub LongRunningMethod(SomeString As String, SomeInt as Int)
End Sub
```

must be altered to:

```
Public Sub LongRunningMethod(PleaseWait As PleaseWaitDialog, Args As List(Of Object))
    Dim SomeString As String = Args(0)
    Dim SomeInt as Integer = Args(1)
End Sub
```

I would prefer to find some way of keeping type safety on these long-running methods.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can understand it needing whatever arguments but why does the long running function need to have access to the `PleaseWaitDialog` object?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd written a line about that. The long-running functions are being altered to send messages to the PleaseWaitDialog itself. "Currently Processing X of Y", that sort of thing.